# WifiManager reconnect returns true but does not connect

Tags: android, android-networking

My app creates an adhoc connection if the signal is strong enough. Unfortunately Android does not allow multiple WIFI networks so I have to disconnect the current one. When the signal becomes to weak I want to reconnect to the previous one.

I store the SSID of the previous connection in a SharedPreference and then I use the following code:

```
 for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
    if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
         wifiManager.disconnect();
         wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
         boolean success = wifiManager.reconnect();
         if (!success) {
            wifiManager.reassociate();
         }
    }
 }
```

The code is working and `WifiManger.reconnect();` returns true but I'm not connected to the previous network.

This is the configuration of my home network which I want to reconnect:

```
ID: 10 SSID: ""WLAN.Tele2.net"" BSSID: null FQDN: null REALM: null PRIO: 0
 KeyMgmt: NONE Protocols: WPA RSN
 AuthAlgorithms:
 PairwiseCiphers: TKIP CCMP
 GroupCiphers: WEP40 WEP104 TKIP CCMP
 PSK: 
Enterprise config:
password NULL
subject_match NULL
engine 0
client_cert NULL
ca_cert NULL
anonymous_identity NULL
phase1 NULL
identity NULL
key_id NULL
engine_id NULL
phase2 NULL
sim_slot_id NULL
eap NULL
IP config:
IP assignment: DHCP
Proxy settings: NONE
 autoJoinBSSID=any
triggeredLow: 0 triggeredBad: 0 triggeredNotHigh: 0
ticksLow: 0 ticksBad: 0 ticksNotHigh: 0
triggeredJoin: 0
autoJoinBailedDueToLowRssi: false
autoJoinUseAggressiveJoinAttemptThreshold: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The fault were the quotes since I already stored WifiConfiguration.SSID in my SharedPreferences this resulted in double quotes -> ""WLAN.Tele2.net""

```
equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")
```